# Running the CLI in Couchbase Community Edition 7.0.0 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line

I'm trying to run the `couchbase-cli` via bash on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine, where *Couchbase Community Edition 7.0.0 build 4602* is installed.
Upon running the bash command, I get following error:

```
sudo: couchbase-cli: command not found
```

Can someone please point out what I seem to be doing wrong? The Couchbase web interface works and the server is started. Searching and the official docs weren't helpful either or I couldn't find an answer.

Funny enough, if I look at `opt/couchbase/bin/`, I can see the cli there, but I still get the same error when trying to run it with the full path or while being in it's folder.

Comment: For people looking to run Couchbase stuff from bash: I managed to do what I wanted by curl against the REST controller via bash. This does not fix this particular issue, but it did unblock me in my use case.

Comment: When you used the full path to the command, did you use `/opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-cli`, with the initial `/` (it was left out in the question text)? When you were located in that directory, did you use `./couchbase-cli`, with `./` at the start to form a valid relative pathaname?

Comment: Can you please show us the directory, the listing (`ls`) of the file and the error when you try to run it?

Answer (score 0):

Unix will display this message if no executable file can be found in its `PATH` directory list.

In your case, `/opt/couchbase/bin/` is not in your `PATH` and/or in `sudo`'s computed `PATH`

To see directories in your `PATH`:

```bsh
tr : \\n <<<"$PATH"
```

To see directories in `sudo`'s computed `PATH`:

```bsh
sudo bash -c 'tr : \\n <<<"$PATH"'
```

Comment: Note that the user is still having issues even when using the command with its full path.